# How to call function in href inside component.ts in angular 11

Tags: angular, function, angular-material, href

I have this function filterHospitals to filter the hospital. Then I have an infoWindow to display the informations. I want to call this function when the href is clicked

```
filterHospitals() {
    this.hospitals = this.filterByValue(this.datasource, this.filterValue);
    this.total = this.hospitals.length;

    this.deleteMarkers();
    this.populateMapMarker();
  }

  filterByValue(items: Hospital[], filter: string) {
    return items.filter((o) =>
      Object.keys(o).some((k) => {
        if (k === 'facilityName' || k === 'facilityCategory' || k === 'clusterFacility' || k === 'stateDesc') {
          return o[k].toLowerCase().includes(filter.toLowerCase());
        }
        return null;
      })
    );
  }
```

```
marker.addListener('click', () => {
        let infoWindowContent =
          '<a href="filterHospitals()"><strong>' +
          this.camelize(this.hospitals[i].facilityName) +
          '</strong></a><br/>' +
}
```

How do I pass the parameter into the function when I click the href?

Answer (score 0):

```
marker.addListener('click', () => {
    let infoWindowContent =
      '<a href="filterHospitals(facility.getAttribute(\'id\'))"
            id="'+this.hospitals[i].id+'" #facility><strong>' +
      this.camelize(this.hospitals[i].facilityName) +
      '</strong></a><br/>' +
}
```